# Show that $\forall n \in\Bbb N: e < \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, inequality

> Show that:
>   $$
> \forall n \in\Bbb N: e < \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)
> $$

Till now i've only worked out a couple of proof sketches, and I don't have an idea how to proceed with them.

Please note that this question [has already been asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605298/how-prove-this-inequality-1-frac1nn1-frac12ne). The answer there uses **derivatives** and **integrals** which i'm **not allowed to use**.

### First sketch

Consider the sequence:
$$
x_n = \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)
$$

One of the ways to show what's required is to show that:
$$
x_{n+1} \le x_n
$$
namely the sequence is monotonically decreasing. Now given $n\in\Bbb N$ we may calculate $x_1$:
$$
x_1 = \left(1+{1\over 1}\right)^1\left(1+{1\over 2\cdot 1}\right) = 3
$$

Consider the limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right) = e
$$

Now based on the fact that the sequence tends to $e$ and it is monotonically decreasing and $x_1 = 3$, then it should follow that:
$$
\forall n\in\Bbb N: x_n \ge e
$$
Here comes the hard part, I could't prove that $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing. I've considered the fraction:
$$
{x_{n+1}\over x_n} = \left(1 - {1\over (n+1)^2}\right)^n \cdot \frac{2n(2n+3)(n+2)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)(n+1)}
$$

Not sure how to show it is less than $1$.

### Second sketch

This sketch is based on the idea from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086005/prove-that-sigma-n-e-is-decreasing-faster-than-e-s-n-given-specific-sig). Namely it has been shown there that:
$$
e \le \frac{n+2}{(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^n {1\over k!}
$$

It [looks like](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yee5vmpnrd):
$$
e \le \frac{n+2}{(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^n {1\over k!} \le \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right) \tag1
$$

In such case if we prove $(1)$ we are done. I've given it several tries but it gets ugly very soon.

The question is:

> Is it possible to utilize any of those sketches to finish the proof? If not what would be the way to prove the inequality **using anything before the definition of a derivative/Taylor series/intergrals**

Thank you!

Comment: why not use the Principle of Mathematical Induction? It's just 4 lines if you use that :P XD :)

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I would appreciate if you could share that idea

Comment: I mean your question can be solved with PMI but not those sketches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sketch works.

We need to prove that $$\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}>1$$ or
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)}>1$$ or
$$\frac{(n+1)^n(2n+1)(n+1)^{n+1}(2n+2)}{n^n(n+2)^{n+1}2n(2n+3)}>1$$ or
$$\frac{(n+1)^{2n+2}}{n^{n+1}(n+2)^{n+1}}>\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}$$ or$$\left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n+1}>\frac{2n+3}{2n+1},$$
which is true because
$$\left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n+1}>1+\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n}+\frac{(n+1)n}{2(n^2+2n)^2}>\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please elaborate on where the first inequality comes from? As for the second part you've used binomial expansion, right?

Comment: @roman  I added something. See now. Yes, I used the binomial expansion.

Comment: That's a lot of details, thank you so much! And i've been able to follow with the last part by binomial expansion.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: +1, but I found the last step a slog to verify - did I miss a shortcut?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley it also took me some time, had to expand to a polynomial of $4$-th degree.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}+\log\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)=1+\frac{5x^2}{24}-\frac{5x^3}{24}+\frac{59 x^4}{320}-\ldots=1+\sum_{m\geq 2}a_m x^m $$
for any $x\in(0,1)$, where the sequence $\{a_m\}_{m\geq 2}$ can be proved to have alternating signs and the sequence $\{|a_m|\}_{m\geq 2}$ can be checked to be weakly decreasing by induction on $m$. It follows that the LHS is $>1$ for any $x\in(0,1)$: your inequality follows by exponentiating both sides (with $x$ being chosen as $\frac{1}{n}$) and by checking $n=1$ as a separate case.

Answer (score 1):

Another short proof exists, if you use $~\displaystyle\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<1+\frac{1}{2n}~$ and $~\displaystyle e<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$

which is proofed in the note of my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929252/find-the-smallest-a0-such-that-1-frac1xxae-for-all-x-geq-1) .

Comment: Hm, nice approach. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @Roman : You are welcome. It was a pleasure. :)

Comment: I was thinking of mentioning this approach in a comment on Jack D'Aurizio's answer, because he gave a very nice proof of the monotonicity of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2979440/213690).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley : Even if monotony isn't absolutely necessary here, it's of course always good and interesting to see different methods of proof. And so it's good to mentioned it. :)